# friend function template with default template argument

Tags: c++, templates, friend, forward-declaration, default-arguments

Is it allowed to provide a default to a template argument in a friend declaration?

```
class A {
    int value;
public:
    template<class T = int> friend void foo();
};
```

Visual Studio 2015 seems to allow it.  gcc refuses it.  I couldn't find anything on it on the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of C++11, the rule is, specified in `14.1[temp.param]/9`

> If a friend function template declaration specifies a default template-argument, that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the function template in the translation unit.

Until C++11, of course, 14.1/9 said "A default template-argument shall not be specified in a friend template declaration."

(the above is copied pretty much verbatim, by cppreference at [Default template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments), now also mentioned at [Template friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends))

So, to make your program valid C++, define your friend template inside the class, don't just declare.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to keep your function foo() global, you can try this:

```
class A
{
    int value;
public:
    template<class T> friend void foo();
};

template<class T = int> void foo()
{
    //you can use private member of A
    A foo;
    auto value = foo.value;
}
```