# Why can't I call a template friend function with explicit template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, friend, friend-function

Consider the following example:

```cpp
struct S {
    template<typename T = void>
    friend void foo(S) {
    }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    foo(s); // (1)
    foo<void>(s); // (2)
}
```

My GCC 9.2.0 fails to compile `(2)` with the following error:

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:10:5: error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
   10 |     foo<void>(s);
      |     ^~~
a.cpp:10:9: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
   10 |     foo<void>(s);
      |         ^~~~
```

However, `(1)` works fine. Why is this? How do I call `foo` with explicit template arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`friend` function definitions in a class body do not make the `friend` function visible in the enclosing namespace scope to usual unqualified name lookup (although they are placed into this namespace scope).

In order to make it visible, you need to add a declaration for the template in the namespace scope (it doesn't matter whether this happens before or after the definition):

```
struct S {
    template<typename T = void>
    friend void foo(S) {
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(S);

int main() {
    S s;
    foo(s); // (1)
    foo<void>(s); // (2)
}
```

Now the question is why `foo(s)` works. This is because of argument-dependent lookup. In a function call without nested name specifier the classes and enclosing namespaces of the types of a call's argument (and others) are also searched for matching function overloads. For argument-dependent lookup `friend`s declared only in the class body are visible. In this way a matching function for the call `foo(s)` is found.

`foo<void>(s)` should work the same way, because the name is unqualified and `s` is of type `S`, so ADL should again find the friend `foo` inside `S`.

However, there is another issue to consider. When the compiler reads `foo` it must decide whether `foo` can be a template or not, because it changes the parsing of `<` following `foo`.

To decide this, unqualified name lookup is done on `foo`. Before C++20, `foo` would be considered a template name only if this lookup finds a template of some kind by that name. But unqualified name lookup doesn't find anything in your case, because the only `foo` is not visible to ordinary unqualified name lookup. Therefore `foo` will not be considered a template and `foo<void>` will not be parsed as a template-id.

In C++20, the rule was changed and if unqualified name lookup finds either an ordinary function by that name or *nothing* at all, then `foo<void>` will be considered a template-id as well. In that case the following ADL for the call will find `foo` and the call will succeed.

So the code will work as is in C++20 and pre-C++20 you actually only need to declare *any* template by the name `foo` to get `foo<void>(s)` to find the friended `foo` by ADL. E.g.:

```
struct S {
  template <typename T = void>
  friend void foo(S) {}
};

template<int>
void foo();

int main() {
  S s;
  foo(s);        // (1)
  foo<void>(s);  // (2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Clang [at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/k5cQ6J) was able to shed some light:

```
<source>:9:5: warning: use of function template name with no prior declaration in function call with explicit template arguments is a C++20 extension [-Wc++20-extensions]

    foo<void>(s);
    ^

1 warning generated.
```

Looks like such syntax was not part of the language until C++20 when [P084R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0846r0.html) arrived and fixed it.

As `foo()` is completely implemented inside the `S` struct, there is no template `foo` visible in `main()`. Therefore, compiler does not understand that it needs to do ADL and is unable to find `foo()`. Like @0x499602D2 said.

One solution is to update the compiler, another solution is to implement `foo` outside of `S` and, optionally, add a forward declaration to provide default template arguments:

```
struct S;

template<typename T = void>
void foo(S); // (a)

struct S {
    template<typename T>
    friend void foo(S); // (b)
};

template<typename T>
void foo(S) { // (c)
    // Needs S to be complete.
}

int main() {
    S s;
    foo(s);
    foo<void>(s);
}
```

If you try to omit forward declaration `(a)` you will find that you cannot add default template arguments to `(b)` because of [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35155708/767632), and you cannot add it to `(c)` because it's a redeclaration of `(b)` and hence cannot introduce default template arguments.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that rule had changed. :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's a template doesn't matter. Friend functions that are defined where they are declared can only be found via [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup) lookup. When you use the template argments the compiler tries to look for a function template named `foo` with normal unqualified lookup, and it fails. `foo(s)` looks up `foo` with the associated namespace of `s` (the global namespace) and finds the friend function you've defined.